# Why rootScope looses it's authority

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller like this,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myControlleringApp').controller("myController", ['$rootScope', myController]);

    function myController($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.status = "loading";

        $("#myIFrame").attr('src', "Templates/myControllerViewer.aspx");
        $('#myIFrame').load(function ($rootScope) {
            // some other logic
            $rootScope.status = "loaded";
        });
    };
})();
```

It works perfectly when I move,

```
$rootScope.status = "loaded";
```

out of `load` method. but otherwise it doesn't changes state of my view.

Here is some of HTML

```
  <div id="myControlleringAppView" data-ng-app="myControlleringApp">
        <div class="spinner" data-ng-show="status=='loading'"></div>
        <div id="partialView" data-ng-show="status=='loaded'" data-ng-view="" ></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why `$rootScope` since you have a controller for the same!!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak sorry I didn't get you, I am using rootScope because I have some global variable on my app, to set them I am using rootScope

Comment: I suggest you to use `services` instead of using `$rootScope`!

Comment: That's a really good suggestion and I will follow it, but why above doesn't seem to work right now :)

Answer (score 1):

The $rootScope parameter in your `load` callback is masking the one you injected into your controller:

```
$('#myIFrame').load(function ($rootScope) { // Creates new variable in 
                                            // the callback's scope!
    $rootScope.status = "loaded"; // This is now referring to the callback's 
                                  // parameter, not the service.
});
```

So what you're effectively doing is this:

```
$rootScope.status = "loading";

$('#myIFrame').load(function (randomNewParam) {
    randomNewParam.status = "loaded"; // Not $rootScope!
});
```

It looks like you might be expecting `$rootScope` to get injected into your `load` callback - this isn't the case! [According to the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), the callback should take this form:

```
$('#myIFrame').load(function (event) {
    $rootScope.status = "loaded";
});
```

Note that now the parameter names have changed, the real `$rootScope` is available from the controller function's scope again - this will give you the functionality you're looking for! That said, as Dhaval Marthak mentioned in the comments, you really shouldn't be using `$rootScope` to pass values around your application - it's effectively the same as creating global variables. Services and dependency injection are the way to go.

Comment: thanks, am I missing something here ===> as changing function parameters didn't made any difference :(

Comment: Just a note, I put the wrong function signature for the load event callback before - got it mixed up with the AJAX load function. Still, renaming the parameter should have worked - are you getting any console errors?

Comment: still doesn't works, and there are no errors in console as well

Comment: Looking closer at the code in your question: Do you actually have a `ng-controller` directive in your app? Because the controller won't get instantiated without it.

Comment: It works perfectly if I move the code where I am changing status to loaded out of load method, so everything else works perfectly, if I put all of my code here it will be a huge question

Comment: Ah yeah, you did mention that, my bad. I'm not sure what the problem is then ): Perhaps it has something to do with the fact you're using iframes, I haven't really every worked with them in combination with Angular. Hopefully someone else will chime in with an answer.

Comment: Just doublechecking, but you _did_ replace `$('#myIFrame').load(function ($rootScope) {` with `$('#myIFrame').load(function () {`, @Mathematics?

Comment: @Cerbrus I did infact but nothing changed, which makes me think, it just creates a new object $rootScope regardless of passing anything as a parameter or not